# http request to a web server timeout on firts request

Tags: http, timeout, ruby-rack

I'm working on an app (iPhone) that makes several Http Request to a RESTFULL web server. When I lauch the app, the request is performed and very often it timeouts. If I perform the request once again (a dedicated button is in the UI for this purpose) it's quite fast (no time out). Do you have any hints on the location of this problem ? Could it be on server side (I running a rack application on nginx / passenger) ?

Thanks a lot for you help. Regards, Luc

Comment: DNS problems? How is resolved the hostname?

Comment: well, I do not really know. There is no problem if I use a curl from command line but on iPhone (or simulator) I have the timeout at (almost) every first atempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be linked to subdomain dns lookup.... also seems to be a known problem.
I set up a domain instead of subdomain and thinks works fine now.

Thanks and Regards,

Luc